# Alternatives to App blockers?

Tags: parental-control

There are work arounds to using the app blockers from the play store.

For example: If I am quick enough I can access the play store and download apps.

I can also restart my phone and quickly access a blocked app. I can also use split screen mode to access an app as well.

Are there any alternatives instead of using apps that block other apps? Most of these apps require a purchase of a feature, so a free alternative would be appreciated.

Just to clarify I am not looking for app blockers from the play store, I am looking for other ways to block apps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should mention what devices/OS versions you are trying to control. As you tagged your question `parental-control` do check out [Google Family Link](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/212180/3573) and see if it fits your needs.